# Quantmod MACD() line width

Tags: r, quantmod

I am using financial indicators of the R package quantmod. The width of the lines macd and signal of `addMACD()` are very thin.
How can I change the line width of macd and signal in `addMACD()`?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `chartSeries`, you can use (the undocumented) `chart_Series` function for drawing the charts. Combined with macd this gives a better overview. See example below. If these lines are not good enough, you can use the code inside `add_MACD` to create a new function and adjust the line width and line type yourself.

```
library(quantmod)

aapl <- getSymbols("AAPL", auto.assign = FALSE)

chart_Series(aapl, TA = "add_MACD()", subset = "2022")
```

[image]